# Return data from pivot table with whereIn

Tags: php, laravel

So I have `Status class` which has pivot table relationship with `roles`:

```
public function roles(): 
{
   return $this->belongsToMany(Role::class, 'status_role', 'status_id', 'role_id');
}
```

This is how `Status` db table looks:

```
id  title
1   status1
2   status2
3   status3
```

And then my pivot table which looks like this:

```
status_id   role_id
1           2
2           2
```

And now I want to write `query` which returns statuses with `role_id=2`.
Basically it should return data like this: `status1, status2` and not include `status3`.

What I have tryed:

```
$statuses = Status::query()
            ->leftJoin('status_role', function ($join) {
                $join->on('statuses.id', '=', 'status_role.status_id')
                    ->whereIn('status_role.role_id',[2]);
            })
            ->get();
```

But now it returns all statuses (status1, status2, status3) it should be only (status1 and status2). How I need to change it?

Comment: Sidenote, you don't need `::query()` at the start of your Query; that's implied. You can simply do `Status::leftJoin()`, or, in the answer below, `Status::whereHas()`, or `Status::join()`, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query will return all statuses attached to roles with id 2:

```php
Status::query()->whereHas('roles', function($q){
   $q->where('id', 2);
})->get();
```

It uses the `whereHas` method that can be useful when you need to query relationships.

It can do a lot more, you should check the documentation on this topic: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence

---

Quick note: `whereHas` is the "Laravel preferred way" of doing what you are trying to achieve.

However, you should be able to also do it with this query, which is closer to your current code:

```php
$statuses = Status::query()
            ->join('status_role', function ($join) {
                $join
                    ->on('statuses.id', '=', 'status_role.status_id')
                    ->where('status_role.role_id',2);
            })
            ->get();

// I replaced the leftJoin by join, which will exclude all results without roles (e.g. status id 3)

// or even simpler:

$statuses = Status::query()
            ->join('status_role', 'statuses.id', '=', 'status_role.status_id')
            ->where('status_role.role_id',2)
            ->get();
```